# Slow view in MySQL vs fast view in SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

In MySQL I have a view `all_prices` with the following query:

```
SELECT *, 'hist' AS source FROM crypto_prices
UNION ALL
SELECT t.cmc_id, 
       t.date, 
       NULL AS open, 
       NULL AS high, 
       NULL AS low, 
       crypto_live.price as close, 
       crypto_live.cmc_volume as volume, 
       crypto_live.cmc_market_cap as market_cap, 'live' as source 
FROM
      (SELECT cmc_id, date, max(data_in) as data_in 
       FROM crypto_live AS live 
       WHERE date NOT IN (SELECT date 
                         FROM crypto_prices 
                         WHERE cmc_id = live.cmc_id) 
      GROUP BY date, cmc_id) AS t
LEFT JOIN crypto_live ON t.cmc_id = crypto_live.cmc_id AND
          t.data_in = crypto_live.data_in;
```

When I do `SELECT * FROM all_prices where cmc_id = 1;` - it takes forever.

The same view I have in SQLite. There the above statement takes 0.004s to evaluate (same data, same indeing). What am I doing wrong in MySQL?

This is execution plan in MySQL:
[image]
[image]

Comment: view have no own index as lon mysql doesn't find any index that fits it makes a full table scan on the view. have vou tried a procedure instead

Comment: the whole select is slow, even if it is not in view. My question is WHY it is so much slower than sqlite?

Comment: What's the sqlite query plan?

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLEs`.

Comment: @RickJames I've tried what you suggested below. It was faster but just marginally. Eventually I replaced MySQL by MariaDB. From 8s -> 0.001s with no need to change any queries. MariaDB seems to have a bettery query optimizer for my case.

Comment: In some cases, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Something to try changing:

```
       WHERE  date NOT IN (
                SELECT  date
                    from  crypto_prices
                    where  cmc_id = live.cmc_id
                          )
```

==>

```
      WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
              FROM crypto_prices
              WHERE  cmc_id = live.cmc_id
                AND  date = live.date
                       )
```

Together with this index for `crypto_prices`:

```
   INDEX(cmc_id, date)
```